# Search for for file by pattern inside specified folder/subfolders

Tags: ruby

I am trying to set folder and define how deep into subfolders search is avaliable, to find all files inside folder and subfolders by specified pattern.

Something like:

```
b = 0 
while b < searchdeep # here number of subfolders inside
  $finale = '*'+'/*'*b
  fileshow = Dir.glob($finale).select {|f| File.file?  f} and (some magic with pattern)
  puts fileshow
 b += 1
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to find all **.zip** files (returned in an array).

If you want to search in any given folder (with recursion)

```
require 'find'

arr = []
Find.find('/home') do |p|
  arr << p if p =~ /.zip$/
end

arr
```

Search at a specific depth

```
b = 2
path = "/home#{'/*' * b}/*.zip"
Dir.glob(path)
```

**EDIT**

I have the following tree of 4 levels with two files spread in random folders (*stackov-file* and *file-stackov*)

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-118 main_folder]# tree
.
├── level_1_a
│   ├── file-stackov
│   ├── level_2_a
│   │   └── level_3_a
│   │       ├── file-stackov
│   │       ├── level_4_a
│   │       │   ├── file-stackov
│   │       │   └── stackov-file
│   │       └── stackov-file
│   └── stackov-file
└── level_1_b
    ├── level_2_b
    │   └── level_3_b
    │       └── level_4_b
    │           └── stackov-file
    └── stackov-file

8 directories, 8 files
```

I can use the following code to find all files up to a certain level (changes `x.times` with your desired number).

```
1.times.flat_map {|level| Dir.glob("./*#{'/*' *level}/*stackov*")}
# ["./level_1_b/stackov-file", "./level_1_a/file-stackov", "./level_1_a/stackov-file"]

2.times.flat_map {|level| Dir.glob("./*#{'/*' *level}/*stackov*")}
# ["./level_1_b/stackov-file", "./level_1_a/file-stackov", "./level_1_a/stackov-file"]

3.times.flat_map {|level| Dir.glob("./*#{'/*' *level}/*stackov*")}
# [
#  "./level_1_b/stackov-file", "./level_1_a/file-stackov", "./level_1_a/stackov-file", 
#  "./level_1_a/level_2_a/level_3_a/file-stackov", "./level_1_a/level_2_a/level_3_a/stackov-file"
# ]

4.times.flat_map {|level| Dir.glob("./*#{'/*' *level}/*stackov*")}
# [
#   "./level_1_b/stackov-file", "./level_1_a/file-stackov", "./level_1_a/stackov-file", 
#   "./level_1_a/level_2_a/level_3_a/file-stackov", "./level_1_a/level_2_a/level_3_a/stackov-file", 
#   "./level_1_b/level_2_b/level_3_b/level_4_b/stackov-file", "./level_1_a/level_2_a/level_3_a/level_4_a/file-stackov", 
#   "./level_1_a/level_2_a/level_3_a/level_4_a/stackov-file"
# ]
```

Comment: The main problem is how to connect this two parts.
For example, i try to search for file with part *stackov* in its name - this is first criteria. And at the same time needs to get all *stackov* files that lies not deeper that 3 subfolders (for example) inside main directory - second criteria.